# problem of costmap_2d in ros hydro

Tags: ros, navigation, eigen, ros-hydro, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I encounter a problem when using the "new version" costmap_2d in ros hydro. I tested it with costmap_2d_node with the proper parameters, but the program stopped because of the famous warning information from eigen:

/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

And I tried to use gdb to get some more details about this crash, and it seems that the problem comes from the observation_buffer.cpp file in the costmap_2d package, as it deals with the pcl point cloud. The last several calls before the crash are shown below:

#1  0xb715f1df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#2  0xb7162825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#3  0xb7158085 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#4  0xb7158137 in __assert_fail () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

#5  0xb76abff1 in ?? () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcostmap_2d.so

#6  0xb76b4682 in costmap_2d::ObservationBuffer::bufferCloud(pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ const&) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcostmap_2d.so

#7  0xb76b4a61 in costmap_2d::ObservationBuffer::bufferCloud(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void > const&) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcostmap_2d.so

#8  0xb2228421 in costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer::laserScanCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::ObservationBuffer> const&) ()
from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liblayers.so

#9  0xb2231eb3 in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::*mfi::mf2<void, costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan*std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::ObservationBuffer> const&>, boost::*bi::list3boost::_bi::value<costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer*, boost::arg<1>, boost::*bi::valueboost::shared_ptr<costmap_2d::ObservationBuffer > > >, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan*std::allocator<void > const> const&>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan*std::allocator<void > const> const&) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liblayers.so

#10 0xb223a346 in boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const>) ()
from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liblayers.so

#11 0xb225adae in message_filters::CallbackHelper1Tboost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void > const> const&, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > >::call(ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const> const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liblayers.so

#12 0xb22455be in message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > >::signalMessage(ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void > const> const&) ()
from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liblayers.so

I never had this problem before. My os is ubuntu precise 32bit. Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69322/problem-of-costmap_2d-in-ros-hydro/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-04**:
Still there the error? It always happens or just randomly? I show something similar when using pointclouds with costmaps. But it was while preparing a demo, so no way to stop and debug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did this already get resolved here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/105 ?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on 2013-12-10**:
Yes! Sorry for such late response...